# Windows Azure Virtual Machine, Attaching New Disk

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am new to Azure Virtual Machines. I tried to add an new disk (Read/Write) to an existing Virtual Machine from the portal. But it is not showing in the Machine's volumes. Is there any steps I need to follow so that I can use the Disk as a new Volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you mean you don't see it in your disk management? or just not in explorer? check disk management first and attach the disk as a volume there , if it isn't showing up there then something went wrong with the atachment